# What to write in the section "what will be the impact of proposed research on development of applicants academic profile"?

Tags: application, postdocs

I am applying for a post-doc fellowship and one of the section in the application form is "what will be the impact of proposed research on development of applicants academic profile".

I have a limit of 1500 characters. What exactly should I write in this section? The research proposal and an abstract of it are in different sections (as well as the list of my main publications and my CV). If I understand it properly, it is not the same as statement of purpose.

Should I mention my current or past interests/skills/research? Or write only about my future? I have no idea how will my fellowship and up if I am successful or not with publications etc. So how can I know what will be the impact on my future? I hope for the best of course, but I pressume I cannot base this section on my dreams. Or can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You should not base this document on your dreams, but on your plans.***

You need to write about the impact of the position on your academic profile in view of its potential effects on your depicted plans for the future. In contrast to the SoP, you better merely focus on the future and denouements, in this case.

As a matter of fact, every post-doc researcher has implicit mental themes, corresponding to his/her plans for joining the academia in a specific manner. For example, just consider a researcher, who does work in the field of biomedical engineering. He/she might be eager to chase a typical faculty position in the realm of the tissue engineering. Furthermore, suppose that he/she has applied for a post-doc position about the design and manipulation of the chemical polymers to invent new kinds of the cardiovascular tissues. Now, if he/she is supposed ***to declare the impact of this project on development of his/her academic profile***, he/she could assert that this project would, considerably, expand his mind not only to dig into the more multidisciplinary projects between different departments, but also even to show the probable tendency to join a variety of departments, such as medical and science, instead of the engineering schools.

That was just a typical reasonable justification for declaration of the potential impact. You need to determine the outcomes of the program upon your specific case and elaborate them, efficiently.